# Why are the correct array values not getting printed?

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, nested

I'm trying to print the marks of the rollNumber array using only nested if else. However, the output that I'm getting is:

```
111 Honors
111 First Division
333 Fail
```

Whereas the output should be

```
111 Honors
222 First Division
333 Fail
444 Second Division
```

Where am I going wrong? The code that I've written is stated below:

```
public class JavaApplication53 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int rollNumber[]={111, 222, 333, 444};
        int marks[]={81, 75, 43, 58};
        
        for(int i=0; i<rollNumber.length; i++) {
            if(marks[i]>49) {
                if(marks[i]>79) {
                    System.out.println(rollNumber[i] + " Honors");
                
                    if(marks[i]>59){
                        System.out.println(rollNumber[i] + " First Division");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(rollNumber[i] + " Second Division");
                    }
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println(rollNumber[i]+ " Fail");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Only tangentially related, but consistent indentation would help understand the nesting structure more easily. (And would likely help you see the logical error.)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp You're right--I did the indentation in my head and still didn't see it; it wasn't until I formatted it that it was super-obvious.

Comment: Can you specify the rules?

Comment: @AdriaanKoster The rules are there, just implemented incorrectly, e.g., if a mark is > 79 a nested check for <= 59 will always fail.

Comment: @DaveNewton Would you accept an incorrect implementation as your requirements specification? Also I think OP himself might understand the problem better if he takes the time to write down the specifications.

Comment: @AdriaanKoster IMO the requirements are clear, if only implied (and it seems like others came to roughly the same conclusion). One way we can help new devs/users is by using our experience to help not *just* by asking for more information, but by understanding how code is *likely* intended to work and pointing out clear logical flaws. YMMV.

Comment: Thank you all. Your suggestions helped me understand my logical flaw. I was so off with the nested if...else structure. I got it now.

Comment: Ok my final remark @DaveNewton: I really think an important part of being a good developer is not to jump into assumptions about how something is supposed to work, and also to take the time to think about the requirements and spot any flaws or omissions before you start typing.

Comment: @AdriaanKoster The OP knows the requirements, they just weren't explicitly communicated in the question. The flaw in the code was clear. Feel free to think I'm not a "good developer"--I'm more interested in helping people and not being gate-keepy, but you do you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your logic is off.** If you've already tested for `>79`, it does not make sense to test for `>59` in the `if` clause. Use the `else` clause instead. The innermost `if` should be in the `else` of the `if` it is in.

```
if(marks[i]>79) {
......
} else {
    //move this if from the if clause to here: else clause
    if(marks[i]>59){
      .......
    }
}
```

Alternatively, it pays to be systematic so you do not confuse yourself. You started off with testing the lowest points - 49 - and then followed that by testing the highest points - 79. Maybe 49, 59, 79 would avoid confusion as follows:

```
if(marks[i]>49) {
    if(marks[i]>59) {
        if(marks[i]>79) {
            System.out.println(rollNumber[i] + " Honors");
        } else {
            System.out.println(rollNumber[i] + " First Division");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println(rollNumber[i] + " Second Division");
    }
} else {
    System.out.println(rollNumber[i]+ " Fail");
}
```

OR:

```
if(marks[i]>79) {
    System.out.println(rollNumber[i] + " Honors");
} else if(marks[i]>59) {
    System.out.println(rollNumber[i] + " First Division");
} else if(marks[i]>49) {
    System.out.println(rollNumber[i] + " Second Division");
} else {
    System.out.println(rollNumber[i]+ " Fail");
}
```

Comment: You just went inside my head. It's interesting how you implemented this logic. I got it resolved  and mine is different. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could be of help @KonarkBaggal!

Answer (score 1):

I've improved your code. Use this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int rollNumber[]={111, 222, 333, 444};
    int marks[]={81, 75, 43, 58};
    
    for(int i=0; i<rollNumber.length; i++) {
        if(marks[i]>79) {
            System.out.println(rollNumber[i] + " Honors");
        } else if(marks[i]>59) {
            System.out.println(rollNumber[i] + " First Division");
        } else if(marks[i]>49) {
            System.out.println(rollNumber[i] + " Second Division");
        } else {
            System.out.println(rollNumber[i] + " Fail");
        }
    }
}
```

Hope the problem gets better!

Comment: Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime

Comment: @SunghyeonLee Thank you for the code. It's just that I've already implemented this logic with the else if structure. I was just challenging myself to do it with the nested if...else structure to better my basics. I succeeded.

Comment: @AdriaanKoster Indeed the right advice.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the expected behavior is really, but this is clearly an issue:

```
if(marks[i]>79) {
    System.out.println(rollNumber[i] + " Honors");                
        if(marks[i]>59){
            System.out.println(rollNumber[i] + " First Division");
        } else {
            System.out.println(rollNumber[i] + " Second Division");
        }
```

if marks[i] > 79 it will always be > 59, so the else will never be entered

EDIT: Instead of working with arrays and using the index i to take the corresponding values from them, you could create a domain model using classes:

```
class Category {
    final String name;
    final int boundary;

    Category(String name, int boundary) {
        this.name = name;
        this.boundary = boundary;
    }
}

class Grade {
    final int mark;
    final int rollNumber;

    Grade(int mark, int rollNumber) {
        this.mark = mark;
        this.rollNumber = rollNumber;
    }
}
```

(getters and setters omitted)

This can clarify the meaning of your code.

EDIT 2: And then you can do this

```
  Category[] categories = new Category[]{
        new Category("Honors", 80),
        new Category("First Division", 60),
        new Category("Second Division", 50),
        new Category("Fail", Integer.MIN_VALUE)
    };

    Grade[] grades = new Grade[]{
        new Grade(81, 111),
        new Grade(75, 222),
        new Grade(43, 333),
        new Grade(58, 444)
    };

    for (Grade grade : grades) {
        for (Category category : categories) {
            if (grade.mark >= category.boundary) {
                System.out.printf("%s %s%n", grade.rollNumber, category.name);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right with the logical part. I see it now.